# jwplayer play one video and stop all of the others

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I have multiple jwplayer videos on my page with the following config:

```
$(function(){
    //add attributes to your ".video" DIV placeholder to customimize output
    //example: data-autostart="true" - see customSettings Object below.
    if (typeof(jwplayer) !== 'undefined'){
        $('.video').each(function(){
            var vid = $(this),
            videoSettings = {},
            settings = {
                autostart: false,
                width: '100%',
                aspectratio: '16:9',
                image: ''
            },
            customSettings = {
                autostart: vid.attr('data-autostart'),
                width: vid.attr('data-width'),
                aspectratio: vid.attr('data-aspectratio'),
                image: vid.attr('data-image')
            };
            $.extend(videoSettings, settings, customSettings);

            var playerInstance = jwplayer( vid.attr('id') ).setup({
                primary: "flash",
                file: Drupal.settings.basePath + $(this).attr('data-src'),
                autostart: videoSettings.autostart,
                aspectratio: videoSettings.aspectratio,
                image: Drupal.settings.basePath + videoSettings.image,
                skin: "glow",
                stretching: "exactfit",
                width: videoSettings.width,
                ga:{idstring: videoSettings.videotitle,
                    trackingobject: "pageTracker"
                   }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

I have tried to add this:

```
                events: {
                    onReady: function ()
                    {
                        jwplayer($('.video').id).stop();
                    }
                },
```

but I am getting the following error:

[.PPAPIContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_ENUM : glTexImage2D: target was GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB

is there a way to make all other videos stop when one is played?

Comment: Do you have a link for this

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me...

```
  if(typeof jwplayer().stop === "function" ){
      jwplayer().stop();
  }
```